# State not updating in useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem similar to the following one, I am having a component in my app (a table), inside this table I have list of rows, and each row has a button called "**change password**", if the user clicked on **change password** say for example for user x, a modal will show. Inside this modal there is a text field, where you have to write a new password for the user.

The problem is that the textfield that lives inside this modal doesn't update. and the reason is that it's inside useffect.

You might say, okay, it's simple, just pass the state variable of that text field inside the dependency array of the useEffect. Okay, first of all. you're right. but the problem is that if the state of the useEffect changed, it will cause two problems:

1. the modal will flash (show it's animation) quickly on each keyboard keystroke.
2. the whole list of users (the table of the users) will re-render again (which is quite big actually).

I know my explaining is like an egg. but here's the summary of 3 hours of trying to demonstrate my problem in a sample, I couldn't come up with a more obvious example, so I'm sorry.

The following sample shows not the same problem, but.. maybe... it's the same problem (not sure). The idea is... You have a list of items (let's say it has 99999 rows), and there's a table that has a TextField on each row, if you changed any of the text fields, I know, it's not a problem, it's going to update the state everywhere.. anyway, the problem is if you opened the console, you'll see the output "rerendering the whole thing!" getting printed out every time you press any key on your keyboard.

Now it's normal to be like that, however, remember, our list has 99999x items, which means that the list is going to render again and again every time.

In the case of my app, I couldn't split the **showModal** logic from the useEffect because the modal has particular information related exclusively to the current row in the `.map()` loop. For example, to attach the ideas here, in the following example, it's the `placeholder` prop on the input element, look... it has `doc.id`, i.e. the scope of the current tick of the loop is the only way I can access this value.

now without speaking too much, here's the (very bad sample) I was able to come up with.

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const data = [
    // very long list
    {
      id: 1
    },
    {
      id: 2
    },
    {
      id: 3
    }
    // ... 999.999.99.9.99999.999999x times longer...etc
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    // say for example this is a conditional rendering after an async task
    console.log("rerendering the whole thing!");
    setContent(
      <table>
        {data.map((doc) => (
          <tr key={doc.id}>
            <td>
              <input
                value={inputValue}
                onChange={({ target: { value } }) => setInputValue(value)}
                label="write anything here"
                placeholder={doc.id}
              />
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </table>
    );
  }, [inputValue]);

  return content;
}
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't be saving your html inside of state. That table should be in your return statement

Comment: @RichardHpa, yes, but the rows? they should be in useEffect right? because I'm assuming that the variable `data` is actually coming from an async call

Comment: Yep data is fine. But all of that doesn't need to be within a useEffect.

Comment: @RichardHpa, hmm.

Comment: @RichardHpa, I am following the pattern of, inside useEffect --> switch(true), and inside the switch there are always the following cases (isErrorGettingData, isSuccessGettingData, isLoading)

Comment: Based on that I render the content (by setting the state content `setContent`)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your current code you would need to do something like this

```js
export default function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const data = [
    // very long list
    {
      id: 1
    },
    {
      id: 2
    },
    {
      id: 3
    }
    // ... 999.999.99.9.99999.999999x times longer...etc
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    // your async for the data is in here
  }, [])

  return (
    <table>
        {data.map((doc) => (
          <tr key={doc.id}>
            <td>
              <input
                value={inputValue}
                onChange={({ target: { value } }) => setInputValue(value)}
                label="write anything here"
                placeholder={doc.id}
              />
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
     </table>
  )
}
```

But I also think there will be an issue with `inputValue` as in this format it would be the same for every row. My recommendation would be to make another component called something like `<TableRow/>` and that is rendered within your `data.map()` and each of those have their own `inputValue`